# Bootstrap Css positioning an element to the right of a "container"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created this jsFiddle to represent my problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/L3p70zd8/

```
<must put code to post jsFiddle link>
```

I am building a carousel. The width of the content of the carousel is to be limited by the bootstrap container (the pink bit). However, I want the nav buttons to the left and right of the carousel to be outside the width of the container.

I have achieved this on the left button using a negative margin but cannot figure out how to achieve the same result on the right button. I am open to changing the structure of the html.

Comment: Please do not trick Stack Overflow into thinking that gibberish is code

Comment: Instead of wasting our time by trying to sidestep the SO rule of posting your code in your question when linking to jsFiddle.net (you saw the big, red warning message) by highlighting random words as code, why not just do as you're asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you looking for? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L3p70zd8/1/)

i change it from `float` to `absolute`.

Comment: Not sure why your answer got down-voted, it works perfectly, thank you. I'd say it was one of those 2 helpful people above.